# How to color only the bullet in a unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>Test #1</li>
    <li>Test #2</li>
    <li>Test #3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: square;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
ul li
{
    padding: 5px;
    color: #00539B
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andsf1x2/

How can I make only the bullets blue and text default color

Comment: Add a span inside and color that differently. The bullet gets the same color as the text. Maybe a `:before` could mimick the bullet and be colored idfferently.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/ytH5P/

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Span it will give you more control over the css as well for the texts
HTML

```
<ul>
        <li><span>Test #1</span></li>
        <li><span>Test #2</span></li>
        <li><span>Test #3</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: square;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
/*below are the bullets' colors*/
ul li
{
    padding: 5px;
    color: #00539B
}
/*below are the text's colors*/
ul span{
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a before to mimick the bullet:

```
ul li {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #00539B;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li:before{
    content: "-";
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
li {
  color:#00c189 !important;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work but thank you.

Comment: <ul id="uls">
    <li>Test #1</li>
    <li>Test #2</li>
    <li>Test #3</li>
</ul>

Comment: #uls li {color:#00c189 !important}   try again